# How can I get random data from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to get random data from an array?

See My Array:

```
    
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My Data
            [1] => Airport
            [2] => Md
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Live in fear
            [1] => Science
            [2] => Sc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => State History
            [1] => Government
            [2] => MP
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Real Estate
            [1] => Other
            [2] => Property
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Real State
            [1] => Not Sure
            [2] => NoData
        )
)
```

I need this type of random output...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My Data
            [1] => Airport
            [2] => Md
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Real State
            [1] => Not Sure
            [2] => NoData
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => My Data
            [1] => Airport
            [2] => Md
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => State History
            [1] => Government
            [2] => MP

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Live in fear
            [1] => Science
            [2] => Sc

        )
)
```

Comment: can't you just use `shuffle`

Comment: `shuffle` won't give you repetition (see output[0] and output[2])

Answer (score 1):

Try the following shuffle function.Hope it would help you.

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
} 

$arr = array();
$arr[] = array('id' => 50, 'foo' => 'hello');
$arr[] = array('id' => 17, 'foo' => 'byebye');
$arr[] = array('id' => 19, 'foo' => 'foo');

print_r(shuffle_assoc($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

> bool shuffle ( array &$array )
>
> This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.

```
shuffle($array); // Shuffles your array keys randomly every time.
```

Answer (score 0):

> shuffle() will be a better option in getting out the random value from multi dimensional array.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

**shuffle() Example:**

The shuffle() function randomizes the order of the elements in the array.

This function assigns new keys for the elements in the array. Existing keys will be removed

```
<?php
$my_array = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow","e"=>"purple");

shuffle($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => yellow [2] => green [3] => blue [4] => purple )
//The Output will keep shuffling if you refresh the browser.
```